# SQL timeout expired in C# code

Tags: codesmith

I'm working in a new C# project and need some help.

The system has some jobs scheduled using Quartz api and one them is not working anymore.

I try to execute the method manually and got this error

***"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."***

in this line (the catch{} is called):

```
TList<TbBooking> allBooks = DataRepository.TbBookingProvider.Find(bQuery);
```

the variable bQuery has a query with 4200 id's and some parameters like 1 month period, flags etc.

I checked the SQL Timeout settings and it's 10 min (default) but the message appears in few seconds after the code enter in the .Find() method (less than 2 minutes) but using the SQLMS the query is executed pretty quick.

I'm thinking about run the command **sp_updatestats** but I wanna see your suggestions first.

p.s. The project is using codesmith and this funcionality was working since 2010.

Comment: Lacking an index on a huge table? (Has the query been running *slower* over time?) Or perhaps there is a lock being held elsewhere preventing the query from executing? (Is this a sudden issue for the same number of items?) Also, how is the performance when running the command *directly* in SSMS? (And what does the plan show.)

Comment: I suspected that the issue was some setting in my application because the query returned results less than 10 seconds. I change the defaultCommandTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

I used the sp_updatestats and it didn't work. I create a index for the column and didn't work too. So I found a propertie in ProviderBase class named defaultCommandTimeout set to 30 seconds. I change it in my app.config file to 120 and the query worked again.